# how to add menu in stackNavigator's header button

Tags: react-native, menu, header, react-navigation, expo

I want to open a menu on click of option button in header of a StackNavigator
snack link https://snack.expo.io/@abdulbsit/vengeful-macaroni-and-cheese
and here is the visual of screen https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mR3fL7KtF-BTp8OY9jlZlWvn3y_DGNhF/view?usp=sharing

Note: I don't want to use drawerNavigator, i want to make menu like this https://storage.googleapis.com/spec-host/mio-staging%2Fmio-design%2F1563837804615%2Fassets%2F0B8wSqcLwbhFuSGtLYzhXYWpRdk0%2Fbehavior-menu-multiple-position.mp4

Answer (score 0):

you can do the above using making another component of menu using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-material-menu
and import in your stack's Header button directly and to access navigation props in the menu component use withNavigation - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/connecting-navigation-prop.html